# Ensuring consistent spacing with custom Icon font in Flutter

Tags: flutter, fonts, icons, flutter-layout

I am trying to use [this](https://erikflowers.github.io/weather-icons/) custom weather font in my Flutter app, but I am having some trouble with the spacing.

It seems as if the icons are rendering outside of their containers, which is causing some layout problems.

This code creates the following

```
Container(
  color: Colors.amber,
  child: Icon(
    IconData(0xf05c),
    size: 100,
  ),
);
```

[image]

As you can see the icon is not centered in its bounding box.

Here is an example of another icon:

[image]

What is the best approach for making it so all the icons take up the same space, and are centered in their boxes?

Answer (score 0):

I ran the above code using a regular built in Icons instead and the container automatically centered the icon

```
Container(
  color: Colors.amber,
  child: Icon(
      Icons.access_alarm,
      size: 100,
  ),
),
```

Where did you get those 2 images? I am wondering if those 2 custom images may be what is messing up the alignment on that Container parent. Could those 2 images have any extra padding built into the image itself that may be throwing it off?

Answer (score 0):

The alignment of Container's parent container sometimes affects the internal alignment of Container, which can be ensured by adding alignment attributes to Container.

```
Container(
  alignment:Alignment.center
  color: Colors.amber,
  child: Icon(
    IconData(0xf05c),
    size: 100,
  ),
);
```